# OpenAPI throws exception in ServiceStack .NET Core - Swagger 2.0 does not support null types

Tags: servicestack-openapi

I recently added OpenApi to my service and when I run it and nativate to `swagger-ui` in the `metadata` page I get a page with the message `loading resources... please wait` and nothing happens. Opening the developer console in Chrome I see this error: `resolver.js:842 Uncaught TypeError: Swagger 2.0 does not support null types ([object Object]).` I've tried all I can to look for possible solutions to this problem but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide a complete example that repro's the error, the configuration you're using and a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this error when I use `JsConfig.IncludeNullValuesInDictionaries = true;`, when set to `false`, it works.

Comment: Addressed and fixed in v5.8.1 (https://forums.servicestack.net/t/issue-in-swagger-ui-and-jsconfig-option-combo/8306)